# Programatically import and attach polymer element with iron-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, import, polymer-1.0

I load a polymer element through **iron-ajax** as a **document**.

I get the following response:

[image]

Then I want to **"import/register"** it, **create** a "pacs-pull" element and **attach** it to my current element:

```
// should import/register the pacs-pull element from the response?
// should I use the whole response?
// should I retrieve it as text?
var elt = this.response.querySelector('#pacs-pull');

// how do I import it?
document.importNode(elt, true);

// create it
var importedElt = document.createElement("pacs-pull");

// attach it
this.$.container.appendChild(importedElt);
```

The pacs-pull element appended is empty.

- Should I get an HTML element from iron-ajax?
- How do I import/register the retrieved element?
- How do I create it?
- How do I attach it?

I went through the polymer doc and through stack overflow but couldn't find an answer to my first 2 questions.

Using importRef is not an option as I do not have direct access to the element (call goes through and API).

Note - it seems iron-ajax text is better because it exactly returns the proper element:
[image]

But still I do not see how to use it then:

```
var plugin = document.createElement("plugin");
plugin.innerHTML = this.response;
document.importNode(plugin, true);

//document.registerElement('pacs-pull', this.plugin);
var elt = document.createElement("pacs-pull");
this.$.pluginContainer.appendChild(elt);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVVOGnlOAX0). It explains lazy loading of Polymer elements and should help in your case.

Comment: unfortunatly Rob uses importHref in the video, which I can not use.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read your question well enough.